# matlab change upper case character to lower case character in string

Tags: string, matlab, char, uppercase, lowercase

I would like to take a string and change the first letter of that string from upper to lower case in MATLAB.  Any suggestions.

Example:

```
a = 'Upper';

% Do something to a

a = 'upper'
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `lower()`:

```
a = lower(a);
```

If you only need to change the first letter to upper case, try the following:

```
a = [lower(a(1)) a(2:end)];
```

Check out [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lower.html) for more info.

Comment: That will convert the whole string to lower case as opposed to only the first letter, which what the OP is after. It turns out that it works just fine for his example, but consider for example `UppeR`: that would give you `upper` instead of `uppeR`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want all the letters to be lower case, then

```
s = 'String'
lowercase(s)
```

gives

```
string
```

If you want only the first letter, then

```
s = 'STring'
[lower(s(1)) s(2:end)]
```

gives

```
sTring
```

Comment: I was in the process of writing essentially the same answer, you were quicker than me... +1